# What's wrong with std::strings

Tags: c++, string, windows, class, codeblocks

Hi I am new to C++ and Code::Block

I am trying to make a simple code to test it, using strings.
when I compile the code there is no problem, but when I try to debug it, Code::Block gives me the following warning:

> Cannot open file:
>   File:../../../../../src/gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c
>
> Info: "Multiple information windows with the same message have been
>   supressed."

Image of the error FYI:

[image: Image of the error FYI]

Part of the code that gives me an error.

inside main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main ()
{
     std::mystring("What's wrong with strings");  

     return 0;  
}
```

I realise that this error only occurs when I try to debug a string or a file containing a string.

Any help would be appreciated.

some other information that might help:

> Code::Block 16.01
>
> Compiler MinGW gcc4.9.2
>
> Windows 7 Professional 32 bits SP1

Comment: I'm very surprised your code compiles. It shouldn't ! Are you sure to understand what it means to compile a code ?

Comment: The code you have posted does not compile. There is no class or function named `std::mystring`.

Comment: So after the answers below, does your code works now ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to use strings you must include the file header `string`.   And the name of the type string is..`std::string`, not std::mystring.

```
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string mystring("Nothing's wrong with strings"); 
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I did add it in my program, I just forgot to add it in my post, I will edit it right now

Comment: @Adam The file header `iostream ` is not necessary in your code. `iostream` is for input and output streams.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
     string mystring = "Whats wrong with my string";

     return 0;  
}
```

If you write it in the following way, it should work.
It's safer to define strings like I showed it. It will be also easier for you if you add `using namespace std` in the beginning of every program if you are new to C++.

Comment: I thought it wasn't recommended to add `using namespace std` as it will add all the code in the std namespace into the global space of my code. Anyways before `std::string` I did use `using namespace std` and it have me the same error.

Comment: @Adam You're right. Adding `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in not a good practice. What you can do is to add `using std::string;` in the main function.

Comment: I did use `std::string` inside the main, and I still get the same error. Typing `using namespace std` `using std::string` or `std::string` will not change the outcome, as the code compiles without errors, and give the wanted results. It is when I try to debug it that this warning appears.

Comment: That's weird. If you compile the EXACT same  code I wrote above, watch at my pseudo to find it, can you debug it ? Perhaps it's a problem related to the debugger configuration.

Comment: Did you create a project, or are you compiling and debugging a single file ?  [Debugging_with_Code::Blocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks)

Comment: Yes the code does compile, If I build it and run there won't be an issue, but when I debug and step into the lines of code, it gives me this warning until I "step out" of the string variable.

I think you are right about the debugger configuration. I will look into the link. Thank you for providing it.

I did create a project, `Test.cpb`, and the file is `Test.cpp`

Comment: @nikau6 He wrote, that he is a beginner, so I though it might be easier for him to learn the basics without writing std:: each time.

Comment: by the way, Visual c++ is a better IDE than Code Block. No configuration needed. It works out of the box.

Comment: I will add that, at the first, you said you code compiled. Which is weird. Using std::mystring instead of std::string, it should not have compiled.

Comment: @io16 You're right, but it's better to explain, in the same time, that it's not good practice.